# AWS scheduled autoscaling with step scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I'm having bad time trying to combine both scheduled ECS autoscale with step scale

In the time when I scale up number of containers, the desired count is lowered because of step scale policy, that is used during the time where the scheduled is not running

how can I combine both scheduled and step scaling and scheduling?

Comment: When you are saying scheduled ecs auto scaling, do you mean sheculed task of ecs ?

Comment: Yes, lanuching more containers